# Неадекватная работа блока input, как исправить?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-form

На сайте имеется несколько форм, в каждой есть повторяющиеся блоки `input` (с телефоном, именем) с одинаковыми атрибутами `name` (у имени - `name`, у телефона - `phone`), когда я вношу изменения в одно из полей, с помощью jquery изменения происходят со всеми полями с тем же атрибутом `name`.

Часть форм у меня во всплывающих окнах `(display:none)`.

При первом изменении всё проходит успешно, а вот при дальнейших начинается "магия", при очищении значения `value` одного из полей формы в некоторых других формах это же поле остаётся не изменным, хотя панель разработчика показывает что значение `value` пусто, а вот форма в окне браузера со мной не соглашается.

Так же бывает и наоборот в окне браузера отображается значение placeholder'а, в то время как панель разработчика показывает что значение `value` не пустует!

Уже не первый день ломаю над этим голову, но пока в пустую, может кто подскажет в чём проблема?
Код:

```
$(document).on('focusout', 'input', function(){
        var name = $(this).val();
        $("input[name=name]").attr({"value":name});
});
```

Comment: Код который Вы приложите к вопросу будет очень кстати для того чтобы кто-то смог Вам помочь.

Comment: Не думал что пригодится. Добавил код.

Comment: А зачем вообще делать одинаковые `name`? - Так делать не нужно. `name` должен быть разный и уникальный у каждого `input`.

Comment: У меня имееться более 30 позицый для заказа, у каждой позиции свои формы, где имя и номер телефона клиента везде одинаковы, а позиция заказа разные, суть в том что бы вводить данные пользователя только один раз!

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо! Вопрос решён, немного ступил, оказалось всё как всегда просто! Нужно было делать так:

```
$("input[name=name]").val(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Вероятно проблема в способе выбора элементов, попадающих в jQuery-набор. Либо ты выбираешь их по имени, либо по классу, соответственно все изменяющие действия происходят со всеми элементами набора. Надо выбирать элементы более точно.
2. Атрибут `value` и значение (хранящееся в свойстве `value`) - это не одно и то же. Когда ты меняешь значение, атрибут не меняется. в devtools ты видишь атрибут.

Comment: Я произвожу изменения через общую выборку: input[name='name']. Не пойму как можно более точно их выбирать, ведь таких блоов на сайте давольно много?